# How to dynamicaly change the "T in" type in Expression<Func<T, bool>>?

Tags: c#

I need to map entities between domain models and view models. 
I have repository in DAL and Services in BLL.
I'am using AutoMapper.

```
T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

### DAL

```
public class TEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

    public class Person : TEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

### BLL

```
public class TEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

    public class Person : TEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Info
        => $"{this.Name}, {this.Age} years old.";
}
```

### Services

```
  // Business is BLL.TEntity
    public Business Get(Expression<Func<Business, bool>> predicate)
    {
        Expression<Func<Domain, bool>> newPredicate = predicate; // ??
        var businessEntity = this.mapper.Map<Business>(
            this.repository.Get(newPredicate));
        return businessEntity;
    }
```

The question is: How to change the internal "T in" type in Expression> from BLL.Models.TEntity to DAL.Models.TEntity?

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't.

I would refactor out all entity types to a seperate assembly which both the DAL and the BLL can reference.